Can I breed fish in Minecraft?
So, on my survival world the only warm ocean is over 3,000 blocks away from our base. Is it possible to like breed fish so every time we need tropical fish or pufferfish we don't have to travel 3,000+ blocks?

For context/historical interest to why this question is so upvoted, an early answer (and I believe the first accepted answer) was a well-sourced claim by a well-meaning user that fish could be bred with kelp. Unfortunately, the two sources they referenced were both misleading SEO generative AI sites that both invented the same incorrect fact "fact".

The false sources in question were gameever and Game Guide.

Sometimes tropical fish will spawn in lush cave biomes, if you find any of those closer to you.

Would it work if i build a giant pond in a lush cave?

As already stated by other answers, you can't.
A (kinda) solution to your lack of tropical fish and pufferfish can be Wandering Traders, they can sell buckets of those fish:



Price
Items
Trades until disabled




1 
Gunpowder
8


3 
Podzol (×3)  Packed Ice
6


5 
Bucket of Pufferfish  Bucket of Tropical Fish
4


6 
Blue Ice
6




No, there is no way to breed fish in Minecraft. The only way to obtain more is through natural spawns. The Minecraft Wiki is a very reliable source for this.

Tropical fish can not be bred, but only spawn in designated biomes. -Wiki


Further support to your claim would be the Two by Two achievement which is for breeding all animals (does not mention fish), and the list of breeding foods doesn't list kelp.

Keep in mind 3000 block in the overworld would be only 375 blocks in the nether too, which far faster to travel.

FWIW, I tried it out in-game as well since the Wiki could be wrong. At least for 1.20.1, you can't even feed the Kelp to the fish, much less make them reproduce. Also, it might be worth mentioning that Tropical Fish can spawn in Lush caves, which might be more readily available than a warm ocean.

The Tropical Fish page on the Minecraft wiki also states that fish cannot be bred. The page likely used some addon (given that both pages appear to be using bedrock edition). There is also a mod for Java edition that allows for breeding tropical fish.

I'm in agreement with the other answerers; as of 1.21.1, tropical fish and pufferfish cannot be bred.
Tropical fish can be farmed, though, and you don't need an ocean biome to do so. Tropical fish also spawn in lush cave biomes, and some caves have very limited water which concentrate the fish that spawn in there.
As long as you protect them from axolotl (which will hunt them if they can), this might provide a source of tropical fish that's a little closer to home.
Pufferfish do not spawn in lush caves, so I'd agree that traveling to your ocean biome via the Nether may be your best option for live fish.
The pufferfish and tropical fish items can be obtained by fishing, although rarely.

To solve the distance issue, you can use an empty bucket to bring the fish over to a nearby pond you find (or made). This way you won't have to travel as far.
For the increment of the number of fish, you can do what Pinckerman said, and also look for more fish and put them in your pond.

The issue is you'll still run out eventually since you can't duplicate them (at least not without some absurd chunk trickery that probably hasn't even been discovered yet). This is only a solution to not have to make the trip as much, and still requires a lot of buckets and possibly shulker boxes.

@Hipposgrumm You'd spend more time and materials doing it than you'd get in return, I think, given they won't spawn outside of their given biome. What Alex just described is just a regular storage unit that I'm sure people do quite often...

Just store them in their buckets then.
